# Unable to scrape data from a website with different tabs and dates

Tags: angularjs, scrape

I am unable to scrape data from the website below.
Is there anyways we can possibly scrape data for the different tabs on the website for a number of days.

https://www.aemo.com.au/Gas/Gas-Bulletin-Board

Tried some scraping on R as well but it doesn't seem to work as the data ranges need to be changed so not sure how to work that around?

Comment: This website is AngularJS heavy and scrapping has to be done considering that.

Comment: Any ideas if R or python will be good for angular js scrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try in Python with with Scrapy and Selenium for example.

try to create a spyder to open de serveral links or import the from tabs, your choise,

and selectors to filter the data.

use the configurations to define the periodicity of each request/job...

Comment: Thanks have not tried that as I have been working with R and not python but can give it a shot.

Comment: Can you please provide some examples for that? I am trying to scrape from different tabs but still not able to do it.